# angular: update specify part of dom by two ngFors

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a problem and don't know its possible to do this in angular.

I have a simple code in HTML:

```
<div >
    <div *ngFor="let item of apiNames, let i = index" class="rescontainer">
        <div class="resbox headline">
            <strong>Name:</strong> {{item}}
            <span class="extra" (click)="getApiInfo($event, i)">mehr Info</span>
        </div>

        <div id="resMoreBox{{i}}">
            <div *ngFor="let item of apiRes, trackBy: trackByFn" >
                <div class="resbox" *ngIf="item['ADS Container']">
                    <strong>ADS Container:</strong> {{item['ADS Container']}}
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "magic" come from click event `(click)="getApiInfo($event, i)`. This run a http.get. This works fine and the result is:

```
[{…}]
0: {PK: 81, IconIndex: "6_1", Name: "VKNE2004", Current Scan: null, PWD Last Set: 4, …}
```

The Result is always part of one of the items from the first ngFor:

```
ngFor1 = Itemname1
------ngFor2 Apires
ngFor1 = Itemname2
------ngFor2 Apires
ngFor1 = Itemname3
------ngFor2 Apires
....
```

Now I would like to update the dome there, where it fits the item from the first ngFor.

```
!API RES get Itemname2!
ngFor1 = Itemname1
------ngFor2 Apires
ngFor1 = Itemname2
------ngFor2 Apires --> UPDATE DOM
ngFor1 = Itemname3
------ngFor2 Apires
....
```

Problem is, angular update the second ngFor content in every Item of first ngFor.

And Yes... that is normal ^^

So the question is, is it possible to update only a specfiy part of the first ngFor? Maybe by name?

I tryed with trackBy but it dosen't work. So please have anyone a Idea to resolve the problem?

Comment: For me the apiNames should be an array of "object"   with property  "item" (the api name)  and **extrat** empty by default. When you click in the button you can store the result of the http into this **extrat** var , and you bind the second ngFor on this extra var ;)

Comment: mmhh it sound not bad. But sorry I don't get it exactly. Can you please do an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do :

Change your apiNames data structure. Exemple :

```
apiNames = ['/api1', '/api2', '/api3'];

const apisData = this.apiNames.map((apiName) => {
  return {
    apiName: apiName,
    data : []
  };
});
```

now use apisData in your template and bind the data attribut into the next ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let item of apisData , let i = index" class="rescontainer">
    <div class="resbox headline">
        <strong>Name:</strong> {{item.apiName}}
        <span class="extra" (click)="getApiInfo($event, item)">mehr Info</span>
    </div>

    <div id="resMoreBox{{i}}">
        <div *ngFor="let apiData of item.data, trackBy: trackByFn" >
            <div class="resbox" *ngIf="apiData['ADS Container']">
                <strong>ADS Container:</strong> {{apiData['ADS Container']}}
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then change the getApiInfo implementation to manage item.data :)

```
getApiInfo($event, item) {
  this.httpClient.get(item.apiName + '/blablabla').subcribe( (result) => {
    item.data = result;
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice :), don't forget to accept the answer to make people understand that this ticket is close